# UILabel updates resets view positions

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I have a small problem with updating an UILabel. I tried a "Pong" Game tutorial which uses UIViews for the ball and the players. So I positioned them with the help of the storyboard on their start positions. The game works well, but if I implement a UILabel for displaying the players scores the trouble starts. With every update of the UILabel the UIViews get repositioned to their starting points. Was there something changed in iOS 6?

Comment: just show us the code

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Comment: it sees that you're using auto layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. The solution was to turn off Autolayout

1. Select your storyboard (probably called *MainStoryboard.storyboard*)
2. Click on the **Show the File inspector** in the Utilities panel (aka `command` + `option` + `0` followed by `command` + `option` + `1`)
3. In the *Interface Builder Document* section uncheck the **Use
   Autolayout** checkbox
4. Rerun your code